# str_replace in model or the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

## Model

```
function Show_all_products()
{
   return $this->db->get('printer')->result();
}
```

## View

The table contents is being echoed in a loop

```
 $i = -1;
 echo '<ul class="products">'; foreach($products as $product) : 
 if($i % 11 == 10) echo '</ul><ul class="products">'; 
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>does/products/<?php echo $product->id; echo '/'.$product->name; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?> </a></li>

<?php 
 $i += 1;
 endforeach; 
 echo "</ul>";
```

The product names are saved as `Something_Something_Blah` I cannot modify the product names as they are configured to show clean URL's and Breadcrumbs.

The issue is that the links in this view show as `Something_Something_Blah`

I tried to do a `str_replace` as `$product = str_replace('_',' ', $product);` However this isn't working.

How do i strip the '_' and insert  `\s` ?

Comment: you cannot run a str_replace on a object. in your case, `$product` is an object. why can't you run it on `$product -> name`?

Comment: If `$product` is `$product = 'Something_Something_Blah'`; then `$product = str_replace('_',' ', $product);` should work. Do you get any error? Do `var_dump($product);` before the str_replace.

Comment: @glavić  
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: views/catalog.php

Line Number: 15

Comment: @christopher the solution is  $product->name = str_replace('_',' ', $product->name);  -- thanks that worked. My error was i was trying to use it before the `foreach` I realized my mistake- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have `<?php echo $product->name; ?>` which would mean `$product` is an object.

So you should call `str_replace('_', ' ', $product->name);`

Comment: yes - i got it- thanks - I was calling the `str_replace` before the foreach which was causing an error

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 $i = -1;
 echo '<ul class="products">'; foreach($products as $product) : 

 $product->name = str_replace('_',' ', $product->name);

 if($i % 11 == 10) echo '</ul><ul class="products">'; 
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>does/products/<?php echo $product->id; echo '/'.$product->name; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?> </a></li>

<?php 
 $i += 1;
 endforeach; 
 echo "</ul>";
 ?>
```

`str_replace` must be called from within the `foreach` or an error will be returned. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As per [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), `str_replace()` accepts a string or array as it's third argument. You are passing it an object. You should pass `$product->name` to it.

Furthermore, please strive to embed PHP in your HTML and not HTML in your PHP. You're going to find yourself `echo`ing everything. You don't need to manually create the `$i` iterator either, because the foreach loop will create one for you, provided you use the `foreach($x as $key => $val)` syntax. You can lose the `<?php echo $var;?>` for `<?= $var;?>` too, AND concatenate with the `.` symbol:

```
<ul class="products">
    <? foreach($products as $pK => $pV):?> 
        <? if($pK % 11 == 10):?></ul><ul class="products"><? endif;?>
        <li>
            <a href="does/products/<?= $pV->id .'/'. $pV->name;?>"><?= $pV->name;?></a>
        </li>
    <? endforeach;?>
</ul>
```